# Update ASP.NET databound GridView when database changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I bind my ASP.NET 2.0 GridView control to a datasource at design time in the Visual Designer.

If the database changes, how do I update the GridView control to reflect the changes in the database?

If the grid was programmatically data-bound, I could have got a fresh copy of data and rebound.

**Update**

I think I need to clarify my question further. If my `GridView` was bound at design time using a `SqlDataSource` data control, then how do I update the `GridView` programmatically? Do I bind it to a new `DataSet` or do I simply call the `GridView.DataBind()` method without changing its data source?

I think I tried this in between and simply calling the `GridView.DataBind()` did it, but I can't be sure.

Comment: SignalR comes to the rescue. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Answer (score 3):

You can use AJAX to implement same. Place your GridView in a Update Panel. Add a timer and on timer tick you can rebind your Gridview. 
As soon as, data is changed in database it is reflected in the gridview with the tick of timer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in way to do this in .Net that I've seen.

I believe the best thing you can do is create a data-update thread that checks for new Db values periodically and re-binds the grid from the code-behind as necessary